# How to print a message using cursors in mysql

Tags: mysql, cursors

I have these tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`User` (
  `Username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_name`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Friends` (
  `friend_username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Username_user` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`friend_username`, `Username_user`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_Friends_User1_idx` (`Username_user` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Friends_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Username_user`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`User` (`Username`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

i'm new to mysql, I want to do something like, when an user tries to add a friend that he already has, it prints "this user is already your friend" , how can I do that using a cursor? (it has to be with a cursor)

example:

```
|| friend_username      ||   Username_user  ||
---------------------------------------------------
||    ale928            ||       dave_249   ||
```

INSERT INTO Friends(friend_username, Username_user) VALUES ('ale928', 'dave_249');

```
This user is already friend of **dave_249**
```